# Grails 3.3 - How to replace deprecated Service artefact?

Tags: grails, service, deprecated, grails-3.3

I'm about to upgrade my Grails 3.2 web-app to version 3.3.

In particular, I created a `BaseService` abstract class (located in `/src/groovy`) providing several helper methods, and most of all my Grails services extend `BaseService`.

```
import grails.artefact.Service

abstract class BaseService implements Service {
    ...
}
```

I noticed that with Grails 3.3 `grails.artefact.Service` was deprecated, along with its superclass `grails.events.Events`.

What can I use in place of `Service` to avoid keeping references to deprecated classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecation is because of **[New Events API](http://docs.grails.org/snapshot/guide/single.html#whatsNewEventBus)** and **[Async Framework](http://async.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#events)**. If you read the documentation of grails 3, you can find:

> In order to support multiple different asynchronous and reactive
>   frameworks Grails 3.3 has been decoupled from Reactor 2.x and an
>   abstract **EventBus** notation added.
>
> The **EventBus** interface provides the foundation and multiple
>   implementations including GPars and RxJava.
>
> A new set of annotations usable in services classes and regular Spring
>   beans can be leveraged to publish and consume events:
>
> **Publisher** - A transformation that transforms a method ensuring the
>   return value is published as an event
>
> **Subscriber** - A transformation that transforms a method to listen for
>   an event.

So if your `implements Service` was for using `Events`, then you've
to update your events implementation using grails 3 `async` and `events`
plugin. Check out the Async framework documentation #events part.